# Why when using assertequal, a function of 3 parameters can be tested by inputting only two actual parameters

Tags: python-3.x

**Test code in pycharm today and found that assertequal does not match the actual**

```
#name_function.py
def get_formatted_name(first, middle, last):
    full_name = first + ' ' + middle +' ' + last
    return full_name.title()


#test_name_function.py
import unittest
from name_function import get_formatted_name

class NamesTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_first_last_name(self):
        formatted_name = get_formatted_name('hu', 'songhui')
        self.assertEqual(formatted_name, 'Hu songhui')

unittest.main()
```

**pycharm shows pass**